# Building configurable react app with additional environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm building an app that has some variations. The core of an app is the same but for now, I need to develop some parts of the app in different way, like another color scheme, different photos etc.
My Question is: Is there any possibility to build an app with specified instance by env variable? For example, I have set of photos provided as below.

```
[{
  "photo1":{
     "path":"my_path_to_file1",
     "instanceToDeploy":"instanceABC"
  }
},
{
  "photo2":{
     "path":"my_path_to_file2",
     "instanceToDeploy":"instanceCBA"
  }
}]
```

And for now, I would like to build my app like

```
   npm run build instanceCBA
```

After this operation, I want to have build version of an app only with photos/whatever I will include in build command.
If elements are not tagged - I would like to build them anyway.
Is there any way to do this in React or something similar to this idea?
My previous attempt to this, was building the app on a few separated branches. Of course, unique changes was written without affecting another instances, but in situation when I've written the code which have to be on all instances - I have to actualize all the branches.
My main desire is to build some configurable elements that depends of choosen instance in my app.
Thanks for all possible help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options of how you can do it:

#1 (the easiest way)
If you use `create-react-app` boilerplate for your project you can use '.env' file for setting environment variables. You can find more info about it here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

#2
You can pass the parameter from your `scripts` that you defined in the `package.json` file. For example, let's say your `scripts` section looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "webpack --myInstance instanceCBA",
}
```

In this case in the webpack.config file you can read your parameter via `process.argv` array:

```
const instancePrefixInd = process.argv.indexOf('--myInstance');
let instance = '';
if (instancePrefixInd >= 0) {
    instance = process.argv[instancePrefixInd + 1];
}
```

Then you can use this value in you webpack.config to specify details of the build or pass it directly to the app via setting 'process.env' variables (e.g `process.env.MY_INSTANCE`)